# Vb.netread line by line in variable dim fickle

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Hello all friends I created some topicos previously but to no avail so I will create this asking and using short examples let's have the following problem:

i need to read line the line of a txt file however it is directly in a variable but this variable can not load all the lines at once has to be literally one by one because my program is an operating system see.
[My program demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2Tv3.png)

and happens the following error it can not receive multiple lines in the cursor that gives error besides them become one when read the only way to read is using readline readallLines and readtoend do not work because it goes all in one line and the commands give the error in the visual studioand happens the following error it can not receive multiple lines in the cursor that gives error besides them become one when read the only way to read is using readline readallLines and readtoend do not work because it goes all in one line and the commands give the error in the visual studio

now I will show my code reading the file, remembering I do not want to read a specific file as my program is an operating system the load command reads any file however do not want it to impra a value on the screen but yes when it receive the command on the cursor simply run the function see:
[my text program file in notepad and OS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQtef.png)
See the code :

```
it at a begin :
Import system.io
dim hastings as string
dim timelapsedapp as string

it at a keydown:
 Dim junt = 0
                    Dim commandtry = cursoruserinput.Split()(1)
                    florb = junt
                    '   Dim txtline As String
                    If System.IO.File.Exists(commandtry) = True Then
                        junt = 1
                        ' Dim count As Integer = 0
                        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(commandtry)
                        ' Me.cursoruserinput = "codestart"
                        ' Dim flow = objReader.ReadLine
                        Dim processprogramelapser As New Stopwatch
                        Do Until objReader.EndOfStream
                            '  objReader.ReadLine()
                            florb = junt
                            'objReader.Read()
                            hastings = objReader.ReadLine()
                            '  

                            '  objReader.ReadToEnd()


                        Loop
                        processprogramelapser.Stop()
                        objReader.Close()
                        timelapsedapplication = processprogramelapser.Elapsed.ToString()
                        'junt = 0
                        ' florb = 0
                        ' hastings = "off"

                    Else

                            cursorcmd.Text &= Environment.NewLine & "Bad command or file name"

                        End If
                    End If


it at a timer:
  If florb = 1 Then
            cursoruserinput = hastings
            hastings = ""
            florb = 0
            oldcmd.Text &= Environment.NewLine & timelapsedapplication
        End If
```

now see the problem of using a stream reader file line by common line:
[the application only read the end line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhiZP.png)

as said of the in the image link the application only reads the last line I searched all about reading line by line in vb.net and nothing made me can solve it so I created this topic explaining further the idea not only use peek until do while I tried to list it too and it wasn't any help I'll be grateful

the idea of reading is like in cmd line by line a batch file so that in my case a txt

My quastion is how i can read line by line in string file ?

Comment: Do you want to read and display the last line of the file in real time？`this variable can not load all the lines at once has to be literally one by one because my program is an operating system`　Could you provide more details about why you can't use 'File.ReadLines'?

Comment: @XingyuZhao not friend i wish to read from the first to the last in real time but always cleaning the variable and putting the next

Comment: What kind of application is this? WindowsForms? Console? WPF? Web? You say "because my program is an operating system" but I hope you are not trying to write an operating system in vb.net.

Comment: When you say "it at a keydown:" do you mean the code is in a KeyDown event? If so, what control's keydown event?

Comment: When you say "it at a timer:" , do you mean the code is in a Timer.Tick event? Please include the real code with the methods where the code is running. The code you included can't reproduce anything, let alone your problem.

Comment: Is `timelapsedapplication` the same variable as `timelapsedapp` - just a typo?